# Does Interlink level affect Chain Attack damage?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

If I activate Interlink before starting a Chain Attack, will the level of my Interlink affect the damage done or the damage multiplier of the chain attack? For example, if I activate a Chain Attack during a level 3 Interlink versus a level 1 Interlink?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a difference in how much damage you will deal or multiplier compared to initiating a chain attack with Interlink Lv1 and Lv3. However, if you start a chain attack with an active Lv3 interlink, the chain attack will start the battle with a Ouroboros order that won’t end the chain attack

> However, if you launched a Chain Attack with an Interlink Level 3 in effect, the Ouroboros Order will be available from the start the battle. In this instance, the Ouroboros Order will not end the Chain Attack.
>
> [Source](https://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/how-to-do-ouroboros-orders-in-chain-attacks-in-xenoblade-chronicles-3/)

Comment: Note that doing a level 3 interlink chain attack in this way will result in doing two Ouroboros Orders (both ways round from the two people you have interlinked) but not any normal orders.